# iOS: How to apply custom image filter with white background

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to do something like this:

[image]

Take an image with white background, and apply black colour only in the rest of the image.

How can I do this with iOS?

Comment: did you tried anything ?

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar to create bar button images. Toy create a context, paint it white, turn your images into "masks" using Quartz functions, then draw them into the context. If this works for you leave a comment below I'll track down my link.